# .htaccess Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to implement a solution using .htaccess and wildcard subdomains so that

http://subdomain.example.com is mapped to http://example.com/index.php/accounts/subdomain/. My rules look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/) /index.php [PT,L]
```

Which works, but disregards everything else. When I try appending anything to the rule e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/) /index.php/hello [PT,L]
```

I get a 500 internal server error. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to exclude the `index.php` from your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) index.php/accounts/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something else (-f and -d), but this works as well, so I'm going to file it away for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php/accounts/%1/$1 [PT]
```

That will rewrite the URL to one that includes the subdomain and the original request URI.

*EDIT*: maybe it needs to be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/accounts/%1/$1 [PT]
```

as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't appear to be firing, even when I change index.php to something else.

Comment: Oh... maybe you need to use the pattern ^(.*)$ (no slash) when it's in .htaccess. (For what it's worth, I would recommend putting these directives in the main server configuration file if you can.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an adaptation of the code I use to redirect subdomains on my own site. I make no claims to it being best practice but it works;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^(www)\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/index.php/accounts/%1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works, but I don't want to redirect users on the site. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test it right now, but would it not work just the same by replacing [R=301,L] with [PT,L]?