# Dynamic subdomain with .htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page like

```
index.php?username=thurein
```

i need to get with subdomain like

```
thurein.mydomain.com
```

how could i get it?

---

I have done like ..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?username=%2 [QSA]
```

But I couldn't pass other variables.
something like ...

```
thurein.mydomain.com/photos/1
```

what I want is that url re write to ..

```
index.php?username=thurein&page=photos&id=1
```

Thanks

If you can help me .. I do really appropriate for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess Wildcard Subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059441/htaccess-wildcard-subdomains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can redirect all subdomains to main domain for example on index.php, in the script you can parse the url and assign $_GET['username'] = $parsedSubDomain; and the script will do everything like index.php?username=thurein.

I hope it is clear.

P.S you can do the redirection using cPanel if your hosting supports it, or you need to change httpd config.

Answer (score 2):

i do this on my htaccess and it works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/$ /subdomain.php?subdomain=%2&menu=$1 [QSA]
```

for  index.php?username=thurein&page=photos&id=1

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /subdomain.php?subdomain=%2&page=$1&id=1 [QSA]
```

hope this solve your problem.