# Rewrite rules for subdomains

Tags: url, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to rewrite rule for make url like

http://abc.xyz.com

instead of

http://xyz.com/subfolder/anyfilename.php?pagename=abc

please tell me how this is possible in url rewrite in php

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting always has to be handled somehow by your webserver. If you are using Apache as webserver, look for "wildcard subdomain". Even better: I found a similar (actually it is what you look for) case on SO: [.htaccess Wildcard Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059441/htaccess-wildcard-subdomains) .

Comment: if you know rewrite rule for http://abc.xyz.com

instead of

http://xyz.com/subfolder/anyfilename.php?pagename=abc

Comment: Really? You weren't able to copy/paste and edit based on the link (and tips) I gave you? A little bit of effort is always nice (or you can wait and hope for a couple of hours if someone is nice enough to do this).