# htaccess redirect subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have the following .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem is that all subdomains get redirected to www.mysite.co/subdomain
How can I aviod this?

Comment: that seems to be what's intended to be according to the rewrites

Comment: Are you **only** trying to redirect when someone accesses `http://mysite.co/`?

Answer (score 3):

Your rewrite rule logic in plain speak is doing the following:

1. For **ANY HOST** other thant www.mysite.co  (including foo.mysite.com, blog.mysite.com, etc..)
2. Permanent Redirect (301) to http://www.mysite.co/
3. This is the last rule to check in the .htaccess file, so bail out

To not redirect your own subdomains, the easiest and clearest way is to handle it explicitly with more rewrite conditions (see example below).  For more kung fu htaccess fun try this: [.htaccess Wildcard Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059441/htaccess-wildcard-subdomains)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.co$ [NC]        
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog.mysite.co$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo.mysite.co$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your index.php file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php($|/) index.php/accounts/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```