# Dynamic Subdomain with PHP .htaccess in shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building an application where I have the actual application resides in newapp.my-domain.com and I also have couple of other subdmains like webmail, subscribers etc. This is a subscription based application & I want to give the subscribers individual sub-domains. so xyz subscriber will have xyz.my-domain.com abc will have abc.my-domain.com and all of these will actually serve the application newapp.my-domain.com.

The target is to get them servered through subdomains and I can then extract the subscriber (abc or xyz) from the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and can authenticate username within that subscriber.

I don't have access to the vhost.conf so the solution needs to be done from .htaccess. I have already created *.my-domain.com to point the /public_html folder from cpanel.

Comment: During the post review, I opted to leave this open because it is clear (at least for me) what you are asking. 
All you need to do is, rewriting the sub domain part to a central file, that can detect the subdomain and the rest of the path correctly and return the desired pages. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1059441/784877

Comment: Hi Ayesh, I fixed that with PHP. I've added the solution below. it works and I can put any logic based on the subdmain I get which I found pretty handy instead of modifying .htaccess. As I did that in PHP it will work in IIS, ngnix where the .htaccess is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. it's actually pretty simple. in AppController beforeFilter I added the following code to get the subdomain:

```
preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?(?:(.+)\.)?(.+\..+)$/i', env('HTTP_HOST'), $matches);
$subdomain = empty($matches[1])? '' : $matches[1];
```

Comment: That's great answer.